# Binding validations does not work when request body is Array of objects

Tags: go, go-gin

Gin's request validation feature is not working when the request body (JSON) represents an array of objects

Ex:

```
[ 
   { 
      "field1":"aaa",
      "field2":"bbb"
   }
]
```

code:

```
type item struct {
    Field1 string `json:"field1" binding:"required"`
    Field2 string `json:"field2" binding:"required"`
}

var items []item

err := c.BindJSON(&items)
```

To be more clear, the validation logic in gin is expecting the root object to be a struct and hence bails out when an array type gets passed.

what is best way to validate each object in an array passed in the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON will be parsed [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/393a63f3b020df89d42695064443760c7d0a0dc8/binding/json.go#L44-L56) and then validated [here](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/393a63f3b020df89d42695064443760c7d0a0dc8/binding/default_validator.go#L21-L35).

The comment on the default ValidateStruct method:

> ValidateStruct receives any kind of type, but only performed struct or pointer to struct type.

You can work around this by defining a struct, as it is needed, that holds your data:

```
type itemHolder struct {
    Items []item
}
```

Then defining a custom [Unmarshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Unmarshaler), like this:

```
func (i *itemHolder) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &i.Items)
}
```

Now `*itemHolder` implements `json.Unmarshaler`, which means in turn that it will be a struct that is supported by gin.

This code should work now:

```
var items itemHolder

err := c.BindJSON(&items)
if err != nil {
    // handle...
}

// use items.Items from here on
```

Please note that your marshal behaviour will change; so you should definitely implement the [Marshaler](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#Marshaler) interface if you need to.